# Outlook 365: Invitation to my private email adress should only be visible in my private calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I use Outlook 365 / i.e. Outlook 2016 for my work and for my private email. I have multiple email addresses. I would like to have invitations to my private email address only show up in my private calendar. For this, I ready managed to set up an additional calendar. But still, the invitations show up in my standard calendar. Do I need to unset my standard calendar? What will happen with all other invitations then?

Answer (score 0):

If I did not misunderstand your issue, I'm afraid that it is not available to send invitations to the second calendar. As I know, in Outlook desktop client, if you configure multiple email accounts in the same outlook profile, each email account will have its own default calendar. And when receiving calendar invitations, Outlook will only add them to the primary calendar of the corresponding email account. If really necessary, you could manually move the items you want to your second calendar.

Personally, I think the best way to deal with your issue is to choose an email account as your private email account. And if other email accounts receive private invitations, you can automatically forward them via Outlook rules (or manually forward them) to your private email account.

Comment: It seems that also when I receive emails on my private email account it still shows the invitations in the calendar of my Exchange Account (work email account). How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. According to my test, Outlook rules seems indeed have the issue that will still leave the calendar items in your work email account. If you are using Exchange mail server, the mail flow rule could help avoid issues like that. Please try the exchange mail flow rule like below and see if this issue could be resolved.

[image]